# Python docx: insert_after()?

Tags: python, python-docx

Right now, I have a "template file" where several paragraphs exist (like education, career, aims, etc.) and every paragraph is composed like

```
1. Education

2. Career

3. Aims
```

---

Now, I'd like to fill these paragraphs with text from a database to make it look like

```
1. Education
some education text from the database

2. Career
some nasty career stuff from the database

3. Aims
some aims defined here  from the database
```

---

I searched through the API documentation but found only a close function called `insert_paragraph_before(text)` - does the counterpart exist?

---

The desired output should be:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document('template.docx')
for p in document.paragraphs:
    if p.text == 'some keyword here':
        p.insert_paragraph_after('some text to insert here')
           ^
           |
           function does not (yet?) exist

document.save('result.docx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "not yet".

What you might be able to do is something like this though:

```
def insert_paragraph_after(paragraphs, idx, text=None):
    next_paragraph_idx = idx + 1
    if idx == len(paragraphs):
        return document.add_paragraph(text)
    next_paragraph = paragraphs[next_paragraph_idx]
    return next_paragraph.insert_paragraph_before(text)

paragraphs = list(document.paragraphs)
for idx, paragraph in enumerate(paragraphs):
    if paragraph.text == 'some keyword':
        insert_paragraph_after(paragraphs, idx, "Some lorem ipsum here")
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Had to edit two parts: `enumerate()` for the `idx` and the actual text (with the `text` parameter) - thank you very much again and keep up the good work (will add +100 bounty once it's eligible).